# Debugging of Lodash chain functions

Tags: lodash

How to debug lodash chain functions in browser.

Ex:

```
if (_.size(_.values(_.omit(this.user, 'language')).filter(Boolean)) < 2)
```

If we want to debug `_.omit(this.user, 'language')` and then the end result with another function `_.values()` as shown in the example,what should be done.

I tried searching but can only find console.log but if we want to debug right in the browser how can we do it.

Answer (score 5):

Chain functions and lodash sequences are usually "debugged" or "tapped" into via [`_.tap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#tap) or [`_.thru`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#thru):

> **tap**: This method invokes interceptor and returns value. The interceptor is
>   invoked with one argument; (value). The purpose of this method is to
>   "tap into" a method chain sequence in order to modify intermediate
>   results.

so something like this:

```js
const obj = { name: 'Ace', language: 'English', age: 3 }

const result = _(obj)
 .tap(x => console.log(x))
 .omit('language')
 .tap(x => console.log(x))
 .omit('age')
 .tap(x=> console.log(x))
 .value()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> **thru**: This method is like _.tap except that it returns the result of
>   interceptor. The purpose of this method is to "pass thru" values
>   replacing intermediate results in a method chain sequence.